# It is posible to pass an Object as a parameter to another object in the constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I have 2 classes, one of witch receive an object of the other as a parameter.

```
$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);
```

Now a situation has presented that would require to call the class B from the constructor of class A.

This is possible? there is a way to do something like this

```
$b = new B($this);
```

in the constructor of class A?

Comment: Have you tried it and do you have a specific problem or error message with the code you are using? If so, you should post that.

Comment: One point to make is that passing `$this` may mean that your classes are too closely linked to ever be useful else where.  Is your object structure workable?

Comment: The classes are project specific as they have the business logic and would not be reused in other projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the current object as a parameter to another class. For example:

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $b = new B($this);
    }
}

class B
{
    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

But, the better way is creating of a factory method in A class, that will encapsulate a logic of object making. For example:

```
class A
{

    protected function makeB()
    {
        return new B($this);
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
       $b = $this->makeB();
    }
}
```

Of course, as @NigelRen said, closed links is bad practice if you want to use those classes in elsewhere. It must be borne in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is indeed possible, but be aware that what you want to do will cause recursion.

```
<?php

class A
{
    /** @var B $b */
    private $b;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->b = new B($this);
    }

    public function getB()
    {
        return $this->b;
    }
}

class B
{
    /** @var A $a */
    private $a;

    /** @var A $a */
    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);

var_dump($a);
var_dump($a->getB());
```

Which outputs:

```
object(A)#1 (1) { ["b":"A":private]=> object(B)#2 (1) { ["a":"B":private]=> *RECURSION* } } 

object(B)#2 (1) { ["a":"B":private]=> object(A)#1 (1) { ["b":"A":private]=> *RECURSION* } }
```

Check it yourself here https://3v4l.org/36e9a